# How to create DataFrame: The number of columns doesn't match

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of
>   columns doesn't match. Old column names (4): _1, _2, _3, _4 New column
>   names (1): 'srcId', 'srcLabel', 'dstId', 'dstLabel'

in this code:

```
val columnNames = """'srcId', 'srcLabel', 'dstId', 'dstLabel'"""

import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

var df = Seq.empty[(String, String, String, String)]
  .toDF(columnNames)
```

Comment: Why do you use triple quotes for the column names in `columnNames`? Any reason for this? Why are you creating an empty `df`? Please use `spark.implicits._` instead.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: What do you mean by saying `Why are you creating an empty df? Please use spark.implicits._ instead.` I create an empty DataFrame because the logic of the program requires it. Do you mean that I can create it using `spark.implicits._`?

Comment: I tried to build a better understanding what you really try to do. What do you do with this empty dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> val columnNames = Seq("srcId", "srcLabel", "dstId", "dstLabel")
columnNames: Seq[String] = List(srcId, srcLabel, dstId, dstLabel)

scala> var d = Seq.empty[(String, String, String, String)].toDF(columnNames: _*)
d: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [srcId: string, srcLabel: string ... 2 more fields]
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is that `columnNames` is a string while you have defined `tuple4` of empty strings. So you will have to *split* the `columnNames` string into four strings and pass to `toDF`

Correct way is to do it as following

```
val columnNames = """'srcId', 'srcLabel', 'dstId', 'dstLabel'"""

var df = Seq.empty[(String, String, String, String)]
  .toDF(columnNames.split(","): _*)
```

which should give you an empty dataframe as

```
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+
|'srcId'| 'srcLabel'| 'dstId'| 'dstLabel'|
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: What does `_*` mean?

Comment: It enables you to pass a Seq of values to a function with a varargs parameter.

Comment: @ScalaBoy _* means separating each element in a collection as individual argument list.

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan - what is the use of empty dataset?. can you show how to use this empty dataset info as a schema definition for ..say a csv file?.

Comment: there is no particular use of empty dataset. Actually a database without data is of no use :)